# How to capture custom created js elements with html2canvas without rendering them into actual DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html2canvas

I need to create a chart custom element in js and would to generate an image of it using `html2canvas`. But for creating an image with `html2canvas` requires elements to be rendered into HTML DOM. However, I do not want it to be rendered into DOM as it appears odd to add it in DOM and remove it after html2canvas does its work. Is there a way to do without rendering it into actual DOM?

Comment: How about adding it off screen, or adding it with visibility turned off with ‘display: none:’

Comment: If I turn it off its visibility then html2canvas will also not make it visible as it uses current css to capture images.

Comment: Can you create the required DOM elements programatically, so they're stored in memory  but not in the actual DOM and then pass that to `html2canvas`?

Comment: That's what I would like to do but html2canvas needs the element to be in DOM to capture it. Hence I am asking is there a way to do it ?

Comment: Is your chart an HTML element? You can add it to a div off screen by setting the position to absolute and the top property to something like 100000. This will still calculate the CSS I believe and your element will be on the dom just not visible